# Understanding units in Kernel Density analysis using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, kernel-density

I'm having trouble understanding the units from a Kernel Density analysis in ArcMap.

The Context: I am analyzing how many structures will be damaged by sea-level rise in a coastal community. I have estimated flooding extent from a university data source, and I have structures in town as points features. I simply overlaid point features on flooding extent to identify which structures will be damaged by flooding. This part was intuitive and very straight forward.

Kernel Density Analysis: Next I wanted to know the areas of town that have the most affected structures. so I used a Kernel Density tool. The resulting raster makes sense (the low-lying area of town has the highest density of values) but I don't understand what the units mean.

Tool parameters:

```
Input point feature: Structures inside the flood zone,
Population Field: NONE,
Output cell size: 5,
Search Radius: [blank],
Area Units: SQUARE_MILES,
Output Values Are: Densities,
Method: Planar.
```

One example class of the VALUES in the resulting raster are 846.8815105 - 1,016.257813 (this class represents a moderate density of structures.)

But the heart of my question is: what does 846.8815105 - 1,016.257813 mean? Are these pixels within 5 SQ Miles of a point? or Something else?

Comment: Understanding Kernel Density Analysis: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/understanding-density-analysis.htm - however, are you sure Kernel Density Analysis is the right tool for what you want to do?

Comment: @PatMac give this a read, it should help you understand the units https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/analytics/how-should-i-interpret-the-output-of-density-tools - basically it is amount of incidents per square mile in your case if I understand correctly